# CRM 2011 - Audit Settings do not overwrite correctly after deployment

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

We have an existing issue with the Audit Setting on individual entities. When a managed solution is deployed from Dev environment to another, the 'Enable Audit' setting is turned off after the deployment (while the imported CRM soultion has the Enable Audit turned on for the corresponding entity). This only happens for a few entities.

Does anyone have any idea why this might occur ? and is there a way to fix this ? Please assist.

Thanks 
Rajesh

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the managed solution "gotchas" in crm 2011. Importing a managed solution that contains those entities will effectively turn off Auditing.

For verification, more info take a look here: http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2011/09/some-assembly-required-unmanaged-solution-gotchas.html

Quote: "What we found is that the Enable Auditing in the following areas checkboxes are transferred from one environment to another, without needing to select any of the system settings for export. However, the **Start Auditing** is not. When documenting the steps to perform a deployment, make sure that manually checking this important box if you are performing auditing on any of your entities is one of those steps."

So you will have to make sure start auditing is enabled on these entities manually. I assume you would be able to automate "start auditing" using a C# Console App as well if automation is an important part of your deployment process.

So, to clarify, when exporting the managed solution, it seems like the following line is transferred:

[image]

Here's a work around for this problem that I found [here](http://www.koorb.co.nz/highlights-and-updates/a-minimalist-approach-to-managed-solutions-in-crm/):

Simply open up the managed solution zip and **edit** the setting for `IsAuditEnabled` to read 1. After that zip up the solution again and import at will.

A bit of manual work but it should work. Also, make sure going forward you remember to do this. If Auditing is turned off you will lose all Audit Data for the entity...

Comment: Thanks for the information Philip, I'm wondering about the 'Auditing' checkbox setting for individual entities, the global setting Start Auditing is already turned on at organization level. I haven't been able to figure out why the setting gets turned off for specific entities.

Comment: I did a little more digging and testing in my vm. I'll update my answer but the gist is, any managed solution that is imported and effects a change (even adding a single field) will turn off auditing for that entity.

Comment: Helpful stuff here Philip. I'll be doing a deployment in the next few days, I'm glad I found this beforehand.